# Unity Lazy Resolve Implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, lazy, unity-container

I have been using `Microsoft.Unity` as my container and have decided that the approach for a lazy implementation causes too much rework. Each time you decide to swap out to use a lazy you have to go add `.Value` or a `.Resolve()` after your variable (which could be called hundreds of times).

Suggested lazy implementation by microsoft [Deferring the Resolution of Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507482(v=pandp.30).aspx)

So I decided to start from scratch.

Firstly I needed an `ILazy` interface (I did add the `Value` property so you can get the actual value if it is ever needed)

```
public interface ILazy<out TInterface> where TInterface : class
{
    TInterface Value { get; }
}
```

We then need an interface and a type that is both `ILazy<T>` and of the interface to be implemented.

```
public interface IContract
{
    //methods and properties to be implemented
    void SomeFunction();
}

public interface ILazyContract : ILazy<IContract>, IContract
{

}

public class ContractImplementation : IContract
{
    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something");
    }
}
```

I now need a factory which creates the implementation of the `ILazyContract` at runtime. This is a long class and has a bit of il generation so it might be difficult to read.

```
public class LazyTypeFactory
{
    //used to stop the same class being created twice
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _lazyTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    private readonly ModuleBuilder _moduleBuilder;

    public LazyTypeFactory(string assembly, string module)
    {
        var an = new AssemblyName(assembly);
        var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        _moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(module);
    }

    public Type CreateOrGetLazyType<TLazy, TInterface>(string name = null)
        where TLazy : ILazy<TInterface>, TInterface
        where TInterface : class
    {
        Type result;
        var @interface = typeof (TInterface);
        var @container = typeof (IUnityContainer);
        var @lazy = typeof (TLazy);
        var @func = typeof (Func<IUnityContainer, TInterface>);

        name = name ?? @lazy.Name + "Impl";
        name = @lazy.Namespace + "." + name;

        if (!@interface.IsInterface)
        {
            throw new Exception("Expected TInterface to be a type of interface");
        }

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_lazyTypes.ContainsKey(@lazy))
            {
                result = _lazyTypes[@lazy];
            }
            else
            {
                var typeBuilder = _moduleBuilder.DefineType(name, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, null);
                typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(@lazy);

                //private field for container
                var c = typeBuilder.DefineField("_c", @container, FieldAttributes.Public);
                //private field for func
                var f = typeBuilder.DefineField("_f", @func, FieldAttributes.Public);
                //private field for func result
                var v = typeBuilder.DefineField("_v", @interface, FieldAttributes.Public);

                //constructor with func
                CreateConstructor(typeBuilder, @container, c, @func, f);

                //private property to get func result
                var propertyBuilder = CreateValueProperty(typeBuilder, @interface, v, @container, c, @func, f);

                //interface methods
                //call prop then invok method
                foreach (var iMethod in @interface.GetMethods())
                {
                    var mb = CreateOverride(typeBuilder, propertyBuilder, iMethod);

                    typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(mb, iMethod);
                }

                foreach (var iProperty in @interface.GetProperties())
                {
                    var pb = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(iProperty.Name, PropertyAttributes.None, iProperty.PropertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);

                    if (iProperty.GetMethod != null)
                    {
                        var iMethod = iProperty.GetMethod;
                        var mb = CreateOverride(typeBuilder, propertyBuilder, iMethod);

                        pb.SetGetMethod(mb);
                    }

                    if (iProperty.SetMethod != null)
                    {
                        var iMethod = iProperty.SetMethod;
                        var mb = CreateOverride(typeBuilder, propertyBuilder, iMethod);

                        pb.SetSetMethod(mb);
                    }
                }

                _lazyTypes[@lazy] = result = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void CreateConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, Type @container, FieldBuilder c, Type @func, FieldBuilder f)
    {
        var constructor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, new[] { @container, @func });

        constructor.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "container");
        constructor.DefineParameter(2, ParameterAttributes.None, "func");

        var cIl = constructor.GetILGenerator();

        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, c);

        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, f);

        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }

    private static PropertyBuilder CreateValueProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, Type @interface, FieldBuilder v, Type @container, FieldBuilder c, Type @func, FieldBuilder f)
    {
        var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty("Value", PropertyAttributes.None, @interface, Type.EmptyTypes);
        var get = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_Value", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, @interface, new Type[0]);
        var getIl = get.GetILGenerator();

        var skip = getIl.DefineLabel();
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, v);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Bne_Un, skip);

        //call _f and set to _v
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, f);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, c);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, @func.GetMethod("Invoke", new[] { @container }));
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, v);

        getIl.MarkLabel(skip);

        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, v);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(get);

        return propertyBuilder;
    }

    private static MethodBuilder CreateOverride(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder, MethodInfo iMethod)
    {
        var mb = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(iMethod.Name, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
            iMethod.ReturnType, iMethod.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray());
        var mIL = mb.GetILGenerator();

        mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, propertyBuilder.GetMethod);

        for (var i = 0; i < iMethod.GetParameters().Length; i++)
        {
            mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i + 1);
        }

        mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, iMethod);
        mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return mb;
    }
}
```

To create a `Type` of `ILazyContract` at runtime you would do something like this.

```
var factory = new LazyTypeFactory("Assembly.Lazy", "Module.Lazy");
var type = factory.CreateOrGetLazyType<ILazyContract, IContract>();
```

The implementation of this would look something like

```
public class ILazyContractImpl : ILazyContract
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly Func<IUnityContainer, IContract> _func;
    private IContract _value;

    public ILazyContractImpl(IUnityContainer container, Func<IUnityContainer, IContract> func)
    {
        _container = container;
        _func = func;
    }

    public IContract Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_value == null)
            {
                _value = _func(_container);
            }

            return _value;
        }
    }

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        Value.SomeFunction();
    }
}
```

As for the final part of the puzzle you now have to register this in the unity container. For this we also need to either register a `Func<IUnityContainer, IContract>` or add it as a parameter in a `InjectionConstructor` which is what I have done.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
var factory = new LazyTypeFactory("Assembly.Lazy", "Module.Lazy");
var type = factory.CreateOrGetLazyType<ILazyContract, IContract>();

container.RegisterType<IContract, ContractImplementation>();

var resolve = new Func<IUnityContainer, IContract>(c => c.Resolve<IContract>());
container.RegisterType(typeof(ILazyContract), type, new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IUnityContainer), resolve));

var lazy = container.Resolve<ILazyContract>();
lazy.SomeFunction();
```

So there is my take on lazy - which wasn't very lazy :(.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, also if there are any improvements that can be made please let me know.

---

As requested by [Heslacher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29371/heslacher), this is a real implementation where I wanted to cache the `UserSetting`s because they will not change over the life span of a request.

Here you can see that the constructor will make a call to the db, which could take some time.  So instead I would like to only do this when the class is actually used, not when it is created.

```
public interface IUserConfigurationService
{
    UserSetting[] GetSettings();
    UserSetting[] GetSettingsForProduct(Product product);
    UserSetting[] GetSettingsOfType(SettingType type);
}

public class UserConfigurationService : IUserConfigurationService
{
    private readonly Entities _entities;
    private readonly User _currentUser;
    //a cache so that we do not have to make the same call many times
    private readonly UserSetting[] _userSettings;

    public UserConfigurationService(Entities entities, User currentUser)
    {
        _entities = entities;
        _currentUser = currentUser;

        _userSettings = Entities.UserSettings.Where(x => x.User == currentUser).ToArray();
    }

    public UserSetting[] GetSettings()
    {
        return _userSettings;
    }

    public UserSetting[] GetSettingsForProduct(Product product)
    {
        return _userSettings.Where(x => x.Product == product).ToArray();
    }

    public UserSetting[] GetSettingsOfType(SettingType type)
    {
        return _userSettings.Where(x => x.SettingType == type).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Constructors should do no work in IoC / DI http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/. I'd say your service needs to take an `IEnumerable<UserSetting>` for the current user, or a factory which might use caching.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you might have a performance problem with `CreateOrGetLazyType`. Obviously, I'm not talking about the IL generation, we know that's not particularly fast. I'm talking about the `lock` statement.

While I'm building a type, **no one** can grab a lazy type from the dictionary. That might become as problem as the IL generation is, as said above, kinda slow.

I'd change :

```
lock (_lock)
{
    if (_lazyTypes.ContainsKey(@lazy))
    {
        result = _lazyTypes[@lazy];
    }
    else
    {
        //creation and whatever
    }
}
```

to :

```
if (_lazyTypes.ContainsKey(@lazy))
{
    result = _lazyTypes[@lazy];
}
else
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        if (_lazyTypes.ContainsKey(@lazy))
        {
            return _lazyTypes[@lazy];
        }

        //creation and whatever
    }
}
```

Now yeah, duplicated code, I know! But sit awhile and listen. :p What's the advantage of this over your current solution? Your first scenario, the one where the dictionary *contains* the key, can be executed without caring about the `lock`. And that's good! You don't want one IL generation to block several calls to the dictionary!

Of course, in my case we need to re-check inside the lock if the key was added meanwhile. If so, we return it.

Also, nesting 101 : Nesting is bad. Avoid it when you can. In your case, you can afford to remove a `else` statement. Instead of setting your `result` variable and returning it at the end of your method, you should `return` right away. This way you can remove the else. (That's what I did in my example).

Comment: Is it safe to do the `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue` in a multi-threaded environment? Or should I use a `ConcurrentDictionary`.  
It was safe  to do so earlier as it was always locked.

Comment: @sQuir3l In that scenario I *think* it's safe. But I'm not enough of a concurrence expert :p I feel like the `ConcurrentDictionary` would have an overhead considering your scenario (where you lazy load stuff)

Comment: I did a quick read and I think that I do need to use the `ConcurrentDictionary` shown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000347/is-locking-necessary-for-dictionary-lookup and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/021a235b-b930-460a-b093-72acbacbb97d/generic-dictionary-operations-and-threadingis-read-and-write-lock-necessary-if-not-enumerating?forum=netfxbcl . So maybe you want to update your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**`CreateOrGetLazyType<TLazy, TInterface>`**

This

> ```
> var @container = typeof (IUnityContainer);
> var @lazy = typeof (TLazy);
> var @func = typeof (Func<IUnityContainer, TInterface>);
>
> name = name ?? @lazy.Name + "Impl";
> name = @lazy.Namespace + "." + name;
> ```

won't be needed `if (!@interface.IsInterface)` so better do this check earlier.

Furthermore this

> ```
> name = name ?? @lazy.Name + "Impl";
> name = @lazy.Namespace + "." + name;
> ```

can simplified like so

```
name = @lazy.Namespace + "." + (name ?? @lazy.Name + "Impl");
```

---

Using `ContainsKey()` together with the getter of the `Item` property of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` should be replaced by a call to `TryGetValue()` which is faster because the check if the key exists is done by the `Item` getter too.
Internally these three methods are calling the [`FindEntry()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1) method to check wether a given key exists. So calling this method only once through the `TryGetValue()` method should be the way to go.

---

If the key is found in the dictionary you should return early to save horizontal spacing.

---

Comments like this

> ```
> //constructor with func
> CreateConstructor(typeBuilder, @container, c, @func, f);
> ```

don't add any value to the code. You should remove such noise to make your code more readable.

---

All this single/double letter variable names makes it impossible to grasp the sense of them at first glance. You or **Sam the maintainer** will have a hard time by looking at this code to fix a bug or just to refactor it.

Variable names should be as descriptive as possible.

---

The method name `CreateOrGetLazyType` implies that it will first try to **create** and if that doesn't work it will **get** a LazyType. A much clearer name would be `GetOrCreateLazyType`.

Comment: Ty, all of that makes good sense.  Will implement in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

While doing some rework suggested by [Heslacher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29371/heslacher), I saw an opportunity to clean up some of the intermediate language generation.
It is much easier to read and debug a class that is not generated at runtime.

So I added an implementation for `ILazy<T>` and extended this class when creating the lazy implementation of an interface.

```
public class Lazy<TInterface> : ILazy<TInterface> 
    where TInterface : class
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private bool _isSet = false;

    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly Func<IUnityContainer, TInterface> _func;
    private TInterface _value;

    public Lazy(IUnityContainer container, Func<IUnityContainer, TInterface> func)
    {
        _container = container;
        _func = func;
    }

    public TInterface Value
    {
        get
        {
            //quick check so that lock is not called
            if (_isSet)
            {
                return _value;
            }

            lock (_lock)
            {
                //double check for certainty
                if (_isSet)
                {
                    return _value;
                }

                _value = _func(_container);
                _isSet = true;
            }

            return _value;
        }
    }
}
```

I then set it as the base class when I create my `TypeBuilder`

```
var @lazyInterface = typeof(Lazy<TInterface>);
var typeBuilder = _moduleBuilder.DefineType(name, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, @lazyInterface);
```

This clears up all the private `FieldBuilder`s and the `PropertyBuilder`.
This therefore also cleans up much of the il generation.

This did mean that I have to update my `CreateConstructor` method as such.
But this turned out to be better as well imo.

```
    private static void CreateConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, Type @container, Type @func, ConstructorInfo baseConstructor)
    {
        var constructor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard | CallingConventions.HasThis, new[] { @container, @func });

        constructor.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "container");
        constructor.DefineParameter(2, ParameterAttributes.None, "func");

        var cIl = constructor.GetILGenerator();

        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);

        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Call, baseConstructor);

        cIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }
```